# How to plot this integral function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, integral

Struggling to figure out how to plot this function in MATLAB.

[image]

Thanks, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

@Rotem 's approach is very good, yet I would love to add few words. Since you haven't mentioned anything about the domain, I suppose function can be defined also for negative numbers. In that case you can use the alternative as:

```
t = linspace(-10, 10);
func = arrayfun(@(t) integral(@(x) (10*x.*(343-(x).^3))/50421, 0, min(7,t)), t);
plot(t, func);
```

[image]

I have fixed the x axis between -10 and 10 with `linspace`, you can manually change that to get what you desire. But, **note that** function will get a fixed value when t is greater than 7, since integral has a bound such as `min(t,7)`.

Comment: very nice soln.

Answer (score 1):

I really hope my answer is correct...

The integral of `x` is from `0` to `t`, when `t` goes from `0` to `7`:

```
t = linspace(0, 7);
sigma = arrayfun(@(m) integral(@(x) 10*x.*(343 - x.^3)/50421, 0, m), t);
plot(t, sigma);


%Test using for loop:
% y = zeros(size(t));
% 
% for i = 1:length(t);
%     y(i) = integral(@(x) 10*x.*(343 - x.^3)/50421, 0, t(i));
% end
% 
% figure;plot(t, y);
```

[image]